# How to set Bottom Sheet peek height to show only certain parts initially?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, bottom-sheet

Let's say that my Bottom Sheet has lines of widgets like the following. If I want to show only the first two lines (i.e., the first two `LinearLayout`s) initially,  but not the rest of the widgets below. I do not want those to be seen initially. How can I set the correct peek height? Hard-coding `app:behavior_peekHeight` probably would not work, so I would need to set it programatically, but how to calculate the height?

Or is there a more recommended way to get the same result? I mean, if I test Google Maps, long pressing a location first shows only the title part as the bottom sheet, but when I try to scroll up the bottom sheet, it feels as if the title part (which might not have been a real bottom sheet) is replaced by a real bottom sheet that contains all the elements. If my explanation is not enough, please try Google Maps yourself.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView/>
            <TextView/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would solve this by using a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` to wait for your bottom sheet to be laid out, and then calling `BottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight()` with the y-coordinate of the first view you don't want to see.

```
private BottomSheetBehavior<View> behavior;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheet);
    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

    final LinearLayout inner = findViewById(R.id.inner);
    inner.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            inner.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            View hidden = inner.getChildAt(2);
            behavior.setPeekHeight(hidden.getTop());
        }
    });
}
```

In this case, my bottom sheet is a `NestedScrollView` holding a `LinearLayout` that holds many `TextView`s. By setting the peek height to be the top of the third `TextView` (obtained by `getChildAt(2)`), my bottom sheet winds up showing exactly two `TextView`s while collapsed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can i get the layout file for this code and if possible the code too.. I am trying to set the peekheight same as the location where i have dragged the bottomsheet. But i couldnot find the value of currently dragged location.

Answer (score 5):

Customized @Ben P.'s answer to target a view id as a reference of the `peekHeight` and made a function:

```
/**
 * Gets the bottom part of the target view and sets it as the peek height of the specified @{BottomSheetBehavior}
 *
 * @param layout - layout of the bottom sheet.
 * @param targetViewId - id of the target view. Must be a view inside the 'layout' param.
 * @param behavior - bottom sheet behavior recipient.
 */
private fun <T : ViewGroup> getViewBottomHeight(layout: ViewGroup,
                                                targetViewId: Int,
                                                behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<T>) {
    layout.apply {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                        behavior.peekHeight = findViewById<View>(targetViewId).bottom
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

In our use case, we needed to target the **bottom** part of the view, so we set it that way. It can be adjusted depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 1):

That's smart!
My problem was trying to `getTop()` or `getHeight()` at wrong timing, it returns `0` if the view is not ready.

And yes, use `viewTreeObserver` to avoid that.

This is actually no different with @Ben P.'s previous answer, just a kotlin version:

```kotlin
class MyBottomSheetDialog() : BottomSheetDialogFragment(){

    private val binding by viewBinding(SomeLayoutViewBinding::bind)
    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        (this.dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior.let { behavior ->
            /* Set "pivotView" as interested target and make it the pivot of peek */
            binding.pivotView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
                OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    binding.pivotView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    behavior.peekHeight = binding.pivotView.top
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```